# Prove $R\times S$ is not an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, integral-domain

> Let $R$ and $S$ be two commutative rings with unity. Prove that $R\times S$ is NOT an integral domain.

This is the best I could think of so far, please give me a push in the right direction and correct me.

It suffices to show that $R\times S$ has zero-divisors

Therefore, let $a$ be an element of $R$ and $b$ be an element of $S$, thus $R\times S$ has elements of the form $(a,b)$.

Consider the elements $A=(a,0)$ and $B=(0,b)$, such that $a$ does not equal zero and $b$ does not equal zero. Then $AB = 0$. Therefore $R\times S$ has zero divisors.

Comment: Your argument is correct, but what is your question?

Comment: the question was proving that R+S is not an integral domain?
I wanted to know if my proof and logic was correct

Comment: Your argument is correct then.

Comment: @Bry If you bothered to use the search function, you would have found confirmation at a question entitled "Prove R×R is NOT an integral domain."

Comment: I used it and I guess I didn't realize RxR is the same as external direct product

Answer (score 4):

Your argument here is perfectly correct, as others have indicated.

It would help the clarity of your proof (and, on a fairly pedantic level, would make your proof more correct) if you chose *specific* non-zero elements $a,b$.  In particular, we could take $a = 1_R$ and $b = 1_S$.

This way, we could always say that we're explicitly using the fact that a ring with unity has both a $1$ and a $0$.

Comment: Indeed, $1_R$ and $1_S$ are the only elements which we *know* to exist and be $\ne 0$ in the given rings

Comment: Awesome, thank you for helping me!

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but I don't think $1 \not= 0$ is usually taken as one of the ring axioms. For once, Wikipedia bears me out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories#Rings_and_fields http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring

Answer (score 0):

yes your answer is indeed correct take two elements that are not zero than show that their product is zero.